# Cost of operations in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an SQL Database in Azure with General Purpose type, really basic one:
[image]

It is not used frequnetly, only sometimes when I test some things on my website, so that I didn't delete this resouce. Recently, I noticed that database management cost increased but I didn't use the database at that time:
[image]

Is there any way to investigate what caused this spikes on the diagram (Nov 22 - Nov 28)? I tried to find information about operations that were executred at that time with no success. Maybe there are some kind of logs in Azure that can help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please consider to open Azure Portal and access your Azure SQL Database, on the left panel you will see "Query Performance Insights", use that option. Use sliders or zoom icons to change the observed interval. Read step-by-step procedure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/eN-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use?view=azuresql#use-query-performance-insight).

While you Investigate this issue, please consider the following causes also:

- Make sure you did not enable temporarily a tool to monitor or make sure your web site is up and running.
- Did you enable a feature temporarily on Azure portal for Azure SQL? Azure SQL Database features like geo-replication, failover group, long-term backup retention, Azure SQL Data Sync, Elastic Jobs create activity on the database.
- Did you enable temporarily features using T-SQL like Full-Text Search, that constantly generate queries against the database?
- If your database is serverless, did you left accidentally a tool like SQL Server Management Tool or Visual Studio connected a couple of dates to the database until you shutdown the client computer.

My suggestion, if you rarely use this database and you have not set it up as serverless, it is a good time to try serverless.

Comment: "did you left accidentally a tool like SQL Server Management Tool connected to the database" - this is possible. Does it really consume credits?

Comment: Yes. This can prevent an Azure SQL Database to get auto-paused and save money. You pay for storage and per-minutes the database has been online.

Comment: Personal experience: Serverless never really helped reducing our costs

Comment: Storm, yes it will consume the credit Microsoft gave you if the database cannot be auto-paused.

Comment: Francesco I had to schedule a process to kill developers sessions  because they left tools like Visual Studio, SSMS and Azure SQL Studio. SSMS had a bug that keeps querying the database once you connect to Azure SQL.